# What is the right way to frame this sentence?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, expression-choice

*The ephemeral nature of humans is being compared to the unchanged and eternal nature of the sea.*

I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatically correct and structurally right. Also, I need a replacement for the word *nature* as it occurs multiple times.

Comment: It looks and sounds fine to me. I wouldn't look for an alternative to *nature*. You don't always need to eliminate repeated words to improve your sentence structure. Setting off *ephemeral nature* against *eternal nature* seems like an excellent device to me.

Comment: You might want to replace *unchanged* with *unchanging*, though.

Comment: If you want another word for *nature* consult a thesaurus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts for your consideration.

Agree with @MickSharpe re *unchanging* versus *unchanged*. So, you could go with "unchanging and eternal nature of the sea".

"Unchanging" and *eternal nature" of the sea seem a bit redundant. You could consider "unchanging sea" or "eternal nature of the sea".  So your sentence could become:

> The ephemeral nature of humans is being compared to the unchanging
> sea.
>
> OR
>
> The ephemeral nature of humans is being compared to the eternal nature of the sea.

I think I would opt for *eternal nature*; it seems stronger and more interesting than *unchanging*. You could also think about whether you really need *nature*;  "eternal sea" may convey the image you're trying to express.

You might want to consider alternatives to *ephemeral*, if you haven't already. According to Merriam-Webster, *ephemeral* means for a very short time. You might want to consider *transitory*, for example, which corresponds to what is by its nature or essence bound to change, pass, or come to an end. I grant you that all finite times are short compared to eternity, but if you accept this suggestion, your sentence might read:

> The ephemeral nature of humans is being compared to the eternal nature
> of the sea.
>
> OR
>
> The transitory nature of humans is being compared to the eternal
> nature of the sea.

I lean toward your choice of "ephemeral".

Two final thoughts. Instead of "humans", you might want to consider *humanity* or *man's* used as an adjective, and to consider recasting your sentence in the active voice. So, for example:

> Man's ephemeral nature pales against the eternity of the sea.

Comment: A textbook answer. Most edifying and a joy to read. As a possible substitution for the word "nature" and to satisfy the OP, may I suggest a gloss: the eternal "ebb and flow" of the sea.

Comment: @IPing7 Thanks. I liked your sentence and enjoyed thinking about it. I continue to find amazing the number of decisions one has to make to write a single sentence: numerous word choices, keep or delete, this order or that,  active or passive, etc. So many possible results!

Comment: @PeterPoint Greetings! Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

*The unchanging nature of the sea renders man's existence ephemeral*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Your answer is very good, but for future reference, take the [Tour] and see [answer], which explain how you need to expand upon your answers, preferably with sources.